# How to create a Python Wheel Or Determine what modules / libraries are within a Python Wheel

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, azure-synapse, great-expectations

I am trying to create a Python Wheel for **Great_Expectations**. The .whl provided by Great_Expectations exists here https://pypi.org/project/great-expectations/#files - great-expectations 0.13.25. Unfortunately, it appears that this .whl doesn't contain all the libraries I need to in order to work with Great_Expectations in Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool.

Therefore, it looks like I will either have to create my own **Great_Expectations**  package a python project with all of its dependencies for offline install.whl or at the very least try and establish what libraries are contained within the existing package `great-expectations 0.13.25`

Therefore, can someone let me know how to create a Python Wheel(ie. Python Package, with all of its dependencies for Great_Expectations). Alternatively, can someone let me know how to determine what module/dependencies are contained with a package?

Thanks

Comment: A `.whl` is simply a `.zip` file of the package with the extension renamed.

Comment: " it appears that this .whl doesn't contain all the libraries I need" – are you aware that a wheel is *just* the package, not its dependencies?

Comment: If there are extra dependencies, you need to download each `.whl` using `pip download <module>` and then install from the downloaded wheels.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami, I think understand your point about having to download each .whl, but its a little unclear about 'install from the downloaded wheels'?

Answer (score 1):

To add new dependencies, update [requirements.txt](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/develop/requirements.txt) (You actually need to update [install_requires](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/develop/setup.py#L22) in setup.py, but in this project they are reading the requirements file to fetch the requirements)

*You will need to clone the git repo so as to update that list.*

Then to create a new wheel out of that source, just run:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

(You may need to run `pip install wheel` if wheel doesn't exist)

Docs: [wheel](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

---

To the second question:  **What modules / libraries are within a Python Wheel?**

Just the package, the dependencies are installed from sources when you install the package.

Comment: Hi Ani, this is amazing. Thank you. Just on the point of libraries/dependencies already included. Will the  **great_expectations-0.13.25-py3-none-any.whl** already have the required libraries to at least get you up and running with Great_Expectations in Azure Synapse Apache Spark?

Comment: Should I be able to run ```from setuptools import find_packages, setup``` directly from Apache Spark? Or will I need to install the setup.py as a workspace package in Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool?
I hope I'm making sense

Comment: Dependencies aren't packaged with your package(whl) even here, all that we are doing is asking python to install the requirements by downloading from appropriate source while installing the package(whl).

Comment: Create the whl with given command then run the pip command on your remote to install the `whl` there.. pip will take care of installing required dependencies as far as your remote can download from PyPI (or some index).

Answer (score -1):

Consider to use Conda pack. It was explicitly created for such a use case of making Python / Conda packages easily portable